# FaceBook like not working properly

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I have used the following code to use FB Like on my website...but clicking on like posts this to FB **"Jonny likes http://www.site.com"** but not  the actual url of the page which was liked i.e **"www.site.com/reports/1"**.

I have placed this code in the master file...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and this in the respective pages....

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://citizen.tricedeals.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></div>
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcitizen.tricedeals.com Take a look at the debugger and fix this errors first.

Comment: hmmmm...thanks...but where do i use ti `" The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided"`

Comment: i mean where should i put this property?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Comment: fix your data-href to the full url

Comment: @Rufinus your answer helped..i have a commenting section on the page for which i am using a `listview` what i want is when someone like a comment it should show on FB as **"Jonny like the comment[comment content] and should link back to that page."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You must implement the following **Meta Tags** information while doing
>   Like press...

1. og:title
2. og:description
3. og:url
4. og:image

---

**Code Behind**

```
public class MetaTag
{
    public string PageURL { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public string MetaTagContent { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }

}

var fbTitleTag = new MetaTag
{
    PageURL = "/",
    MetaTagName = "og:title",
    SiteName = "Your Site Name",
    MetaTagContent = "Your Title"
};

var fbDesc = new MetaTag
{
    PageURL = "/",
    MetaTagName = "og:description",
    SiteName = "Site Name",
    MetaTagContent = "Your Description"
};

var fbUrl = new MetaTag
{
    PageURL = "/",
    MetaTagName = "og:url",
    SiteName = "Site Name",
    MetaTagContent = "URL"
};

var fbImage = new MetaTag
{
    PageURL = "/",
    MetaTagName = "og:image",
    SiteName = "Site Name",
    MetaTagContent = "Image URL"
};

System.Collections.Generic.List<MetaTag> List = new System.Collections.Generic.List<MetaTag>();
List.Add(fbTitleTag);
List.Add(fbDesc);
List.Add(fbUrl);
List.Add(fbImage);
RenderMetaTags(List, "SiteName", strRawUrl, ltMetaTags);

Here ltMetaTags is the Literal control to place in Master page. See bottom of the asnwer.

public static void RenderMetaTags(List<MetaTag> MetaTags, string sitename, string strRawURL, Literal ltlMetaHolders)
{
    //  ltlMetaHolders.Text = "";

    foreach (MetaTag oAgentMetaTag in MetaTags)
    {
        RenderMetaTagByContentName(ltlMetaHolders, oAgentMetaTag.MetaTagName, oAgentMetaTag.MetaTagContent);
    }
}

public static void RenderMetaTagByContentName(Literal ltlMetaHolder, string contentName, string content, bool isProp)
{
    var metaTagFromat = isProp ? "<meta property=\"{0}\" content=\"{1}\" />" : "<meta name=\"{0}\" content=\"{1}\" /> ";

    ltlMetaHolder.Text += string.Format(metaTagFromat, contentName, content);

}
```

### HTML in Master Page

> Following is the Literal in Head tag of Master Page

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltMetaTags" Mode="Transform" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Comment: no i am not..sorry i have no idea about these...where do i put these tags?

Comment: @user1150440, you should put them in the `<head>` section of your page `HTML` code.

Comment: @PankajGarg, **considering** and **MUST USE** is a bit different things ;) `og:title`,`og:type`, `og:image` and `og:url` are [required properties in OpenGraph](http://ogp.me/#metadata)

Comment: oppps i think its a class file??

Comment: Only literal control need to be there. The function can be placed in a class file for common usage and can be called from wherever you have to use it.

Comment: okay thanks...can you just throw some light on how to call this function from a particular page??

Comment: call the RenderMetaTags on the required page and check my improved answer.

Comment: thanks ...just one last thing...i am a VB developer...i tried converting your code to VB but i get errors..can u please give me a VB vrsion

Comment: CONVERSION ERROR: Code could not be converted. Details:

-- line 1 col 1: EOF expected

Please check for any errors in the original code and try again.

Comment: Convert only the required code.which you cannot do. As you know you still need code integration.